# Navigating to page with Tabs widget causes entire page to re-load inside tab panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a page on a jQuery mobile app that has a tabs widget like so:

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="dashboard-tabs">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab-events" data-ajax="false" class="ui-icon-calendar ui-btn-icon-left">Upcoming Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-news" data-ajax="false" class="ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left">Latest News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-events">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="tab-news">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load the page containing this markup directly in the browser, everything works fine.

However, if I navigate to this page from another, things get weird. The entire page is loaded a second time and inserted in a new div just after the closing `</ul>` in the original markup. Looks like this is just done for the default tab.

I'm thinking jQuery mobile is doing something weird with the way it's initializing the tabs widget when the page containing it is loaded via AJAX vs a full browser page load. I just can't figure out why or what is causing it!

**Edit:** I've placed a bounty on this. I forgot to mention that I'm using jQuery 1.11, and jQuery Mobile 1.4.1. The reason I have jQuery UI tagged is because jQuery Mobile apparently has taken the tabs widget directly from there, unaltered.

I log when `pageinit` and `pageshow` are called. When I click a link to the page containing the tabs, each event is fired twice, one at a time. The second `pageinit` and `pageshow` are executed from JS that was dynamically inserted into the page from jQM, and not from the original JS that loaded with the first app load. Whatever is happening here is causing the entire page to be reloaded and inserted into the DOM, with all the JS being executed a second time.

**Edit 2:** Note that this is happening without *any* of my own custom JavaScript. Earlier I was just binding to pageinit and pageshow so I could log when they were fired, that's it. Also, the content within the tabs seems irrelevant as well. Just making the tab panes blank for instance does not fix it.

**Edit 3:** <strike>Here is a link that demonstrates the problem</strike>. I've since removed the link that demo's the problem, since it was hosted on my personal site and I confirmed it was a bug.

Comment: There is no custom JavaScript at all. It's just a basic jQuery Mobile page that I navigate to.

Comment: are you including any js libraries in external pages you intend to show as a tab?

Comment: No, two tabs that are loaded contain just regular content. The problem persists even when removing all content from the tabs.

Comment: Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: No, no errors. Added some additional details above.

Comment: Add `pageinit` and `pageshow` code please. It looks like your multiplying event handlers on both events.

Comment: I said above, there is no custom javascript. This happens without binding my own event handlers.

Comment: I cant find any issue in this. `pageinit` and `pageshow` will trigger once on each page, when you move from a page to another. If you start with tabs page, those events will fire once. If you check demo page of jQM you'll notice the same. Btw, tab-events_ and _tab-news_ aren't pages, hence, no event is going to be triggered on them.

Comment: Okay, I've setup a very basic 2 page sample. It's linked above in the 3rd edit. The problem is clear when clicking the link to the second page.

Comment: I started a question[(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167311/js-error-when-a-linked-page-has-jquery-mobile-tabs-and-navbar-widget), then found your post.  I think your question and mine are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after discussing [more on the jQuery Mobile](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/when-linking-to-a-page-with-a-tabs-widget-the-page-is-loaded-twice) forums, I [opened an issue on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169) and it looks like it's a confirmed issue with how Tabs treats local links.

Answer (score 2):

I will just copy one of [their](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169) quickest solution that works for me:

```
$.widget( "ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {

    _createWidget: function( options, element ) {
        var page, delayedCreate,
            that = this;

        if ( $.mobile.page ) {
            page = $( element )
                .parents( ":jqmData(role='page'),:mobile-page" )
                .first();

            if ( page.length > 0 && !page.hasClass( "ui-page-active" ) ) {
                delayedCreate = this._super;
                page.one( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
                    delayedCreate.call( that, options, element );
                });
            }
        } else {
            return this._super();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hallelujah, thank you!!  I've been wrestling with this for ages removing and adding pieces and thought I was using jQuery Mobile wrong, but this fixes it!!

Answer (score 0):

I find that adding

```
data-ajax="false"
```

to the `<a>` link which you jump from, will solve this problem.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for tabs, but the solution from @uriel works.