# JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 anchor tag in navbar causes previous page to be appended to page

Tags: jquery-mobile

Whenever i remove the anchor tags in the < li> tags, theres no problem, but as long as there is an anchor tag with href="" with no link, when i come to this page from previous page, then the previous page is within this page. Any Ideas?

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="tabs">
        <div data-role="navbar" id="abc6">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#quarts-venir" data-ajax="false">&Agrave; venir</a></li>
                <li><a href="#quarts-confirmer" data-ajax="false">&Agrave; confirmer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#quarts-dispo" data-ajax="false">Disponibles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="quarts-venir">
            <p>Clickez Disponibles</p>
            <a href="testICS.php" class="ui-btn" data-ajax="false">Telecharger</a>
        </div>
        <div id="quarts-confirmer">
            <p>Clickez Disponibles</p>
        </div>
        <div id="quarts-dispo">
            <?php renderShift(2); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bug in "Tabs" widgets in _Single Page Model_. Solution: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169#issuecomment-36005791

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigating to page with Tabs widget causes entire page to re-load inside tab panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864959/navigating-to-page-with-tabs-widget-causes-entire-page-to-re-load-inside-tab-pan)