# JS error when a linked page has jQuery mobile tabs and navbar widget

Tags: jquery-mobile

{{ See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tpzf5iONL9F8ZnoUyuqj) }}

Page 1 is a jquery mobile page.

Page 2 is a page **with** jquery mobile tabs and navbar widget.

Page 3 is a page **without** jquery mobile tabs and navbar widget.

The only structural difference between 2 and 3 is the presence of data-role=tabs.

---

A) When each of them are run as is (you type the url on address bar), everything is fine.

B) When you click from page 1 to page 2,

i) js error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < VM10189 jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2`

ii) the code **outside** `<page/>` on page 2 is run, as you see the alert.

C) When you click from page 1 to page 3, everything is fine (no js error, code outside `<page/>` not run).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody gave [an answer](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169) on the same question asked elsewhere.  I checked it working.  Look for

```
$.widget( "ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
....
```